# Is there a way to remove a snapchat effect from a picture?

Tags: color, layers, photo-editing

I took a great picture of the sky the other day but it was on snapchat and i covered a tree by painting yellow streaks over it on the snap, that's the only pic I saved to my phone but I wanted to know if there was a way to remove the yellow streaking? can it be done with an online program? thanks

Comment: Whether or not it can be done (and to the extent that it can) will depend greatly on the image itself.  It would help if we could see it.

Comment: No way to remove it other than to paint back over it trying to replicate the original. I don't know if it's a feature in snapchat or not but a lot of the filter-laden photo apps have an option to "also save original image" which may prevent this issue in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably remove the yellow line using content aware in photoshop, but it would have to interpolate what to fill in where the lines were. As far as I know snap chat flattens your image after it's saved, so you can't just "undo" the streaks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the clone tool, which is in most (if not all) photo editors.

Just set the source to somewhere near the yellow lines, while not selecting the yellow line in the source, and then draw over the lines.


In most cases, this will work, but it greatly depends on the image.

You can try this and see if it works out well.


[Photoshop Clone Stamp Tool](http://simplephotoshop.com/photoshop_tools/clone_stampf.htm)

[GIMP Clone Tool](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Clone-Tool-in-Gimp)

Answer (score -1):

If you go into your memories, and click edit on the bottom of the photo, you can go back into the pen tool, and click the arrow, and it will undo it.